# Preserve transferred folder's modification date when downloading from SFTP server

Tags: windows, sftp, synchronization, timestamp

I'm looking for an way to download folders to a Windows machine from an SFTP server, while preserving transfer **folder**'s ***modification date***.

Servers I'm copying from uses Linux.

I know that most of SFTP clients supports preserving *file's modification date* (but ***not folder***).

SFTP clients I know that do not support preserving folder's modification:

- FileZilla

  - Seems won't support at all ([Link](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?p=149758#p149758))
- CyberDuck/Mountain Duck

  - Folder's modification date is only preserved if folder is empty. This may be due to the fact that CyberDuck transfers folder first then after this it transfers sub-files, without re-copying folder's modification date after transfer is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My) WinSCP supports preserving timestamps of folders with the SFTP protocol. It's turned off by default, you need to [enable it in preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom).

WinSCP supports both GUI and scripted transfers.